# Sort(), confusing about condition in comparision function

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, numbers, conditional-statements

I get this code from a basic javascript lesson on Codewar, but I don't understand how it work, I tried one by one condition but it doesn't show output as I expected. Thank you so much.

```
var arr=[1,2,3,4,5,6,100,999]
arr.sort((a,b)=>{
  if (a%2==b%2) return a-b;
  if (a%2>b%2) return -1;
  return 1;
})
console.log(arr)

//output: [ 1, 3, 5, 999, 2, 4, 6, 100 ]
```

Comment: Well, what output did you expect?

Comment: Because I don't understand it so I saw it a little strange. Now I got it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it should print the odd numbers first then even numbers, each is sorted

`if (a%2==b%2) return a-b;`

if a, b are both even or both odd then sort them in increasing order

`if (a%2>b%2) return -1;`

else if they are different [ one odd and the other is even ] put the odd numbers first

else a, b are equal

Comment: Thank u for your explaination. I help me understood how it works.